# (Firebase Realtime Database| React) How to add data to a firebase realtime database without key?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Data structure]

I want to structure my data something like this with movieId added to wishlist when i favourite it but i don't know how to go about it. I was using push() but that adds a generated key and then adds the movie which i don't want. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Code that adds first movie
 `` set(ref(db,`users/${auth.currentUser?.uid}/wishlist/`),{[movieId]:true}) ``

Code that adds subsequent movies

```
const wishlistRef = ref(db, `users/${auth.currentUser?.uid}/wishlist`);
        const newWishlistRef = push(wishlistRef);
        set(newWishlistRef, {
            [movieId]:true
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick

```
const nodeRef = child(ref(db), `users/${auth.currentUser?.uid}/wishlist/` + movieId); // id = custom ID you want to specify 

set(nodeRef,  true )
```